# Input does not match output in C

Tags: c

Hi I have a c function below:

```
int method2 (){
    int userInput;
    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &userInput);

    fpurge(stdin);

    printf("You are %d years old. \n", &userInput);

    int retval = 0;
    return retval;
}
```

The function takes the age and returns the same value in a strong sentence.

So when I run it as type 12 as age. I get

```
You are 1606416204 years old.
```

Comment: `&userInput` in `printf`  ->  `userInput`    Read a book to understand why `printf` and `scanf` are different here.

Comment: `&userInput` evaluates to address of `userInput` while `userInput` evaluates to value of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing address of the variable `userInput` instead of its value, use `printf` as follows

```
printf("You are %d years old. \n", userInput);
```

This will print the value present in the variable `userInput`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("You are %d years old. \n", &userInput);
                                    ^
                                    |..//remove &
```

You printed address here `&userInput'.` It should be `userInput`.

Answer (score 1):

You confused the usage of `printf` with that of `scanf`

change :

```
printf("You are %d years old. \n", &userInput);
```

to :

```
printf("You are %d years old. \n", userInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

How come you included the `&` in the userInput for the printf? The `&` evaluates the address. We want the **value** of userInput instead, so change it to:

```
printf("You are %d years old. \n", userInput);
```

and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing address instead of the value. Change in your code to this -

```
printf("You are %d years old. \n", userInput);
```

It will surely work.